# Ubuntu 22.04 on Openstack - no output on console

Tags: boot, grub2

After booting Ubuntu 22.04, the kvm console shows only:

Booting from hard Disk...
GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID set, attempting initrdless boot.

No other output on console nor login prompt after system is loaded. Of course the system is working ok. Is it a new feature of Ubuntu?

Comment: +1 wanna know as well... I wasted way too much time last night trying to find out why it wouldn't boot until I realised that it did - just without any TTY output whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it depends on cloud image you are using. 'amd64-disk-kvm.img' does not contain drivers for video card, probably. Full image 'amd64.img' works fine.

Comment: Godd point. I thought that kvm fully fits to virtualization, but without that feature more useful for me and my users is jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img. Thank you very much for the answer.